# MySQL LIKE with json_extract

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, mysql-json, collate

I have a MySQL query, where I filter by a json field:

```
SELECT id, username 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               Json_extract(payload, '$.username') AS username 
        FROM   table1) AS tmp 
WHERE  username = 'userName1';
```

It returns 1 row, which looks like:

`1, "userName1"` See the quotes that are not in the clause?

What I need is to make the `WHERE` clause case insensitive.
But when I do

`WHERE  username LIKE 'userName1';`

it returns 0 rows. I don't understand why it works this way, the `=` clause works though it doesn't have those double quotes.

If I do

`WHERE  username LIKE '%userName1%';`
now also returns the row, because `%%` takes quotes into consideration:

`1, "userName1"`

But when I do

`WHERE  username LIKE '%username1%';`
it returns 0 rows, so unlike the usual MySQL `LIKE` it's somehow case sensitive.

What am I doing wrong and how to filter the json payload the case insensitive way?
EDIT=========================================
The guess is that `COLLATE` should be used here, but so far I don't understand how to make it work.

Comment: I thought mysql was case insensitive by default. Only case sensitive when doing binary operation

Comment: LIKE clause is case insensitive outside json, with any string. But if it's json it works like that

Comment: Reconsider the use of JSON when you need MySQL to rummage around inside the string.  It may, instead, be worth breaking out that field into a separate column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to solve the case insensitivity by adding `COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci` after the `LIKE` clause.

So the point here is to find a working collation, which in its turn can be found by researching the db you work with.

Answer (score 3):

Default collation of MySQL is [`latin1_swedish_ci` before 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html) and [`utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` since 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html). So non-binary string comparisons are case-insensitive by default in ordinary columns.

However, as mentioned in [MySQL manual for JSON type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

> MySQL handles strings used in JSON context using the `utf8mb4` character set and `utf8mb4_bin` collation.".

Therefore, your JSON value is in `utf8mb4_bin` collation and you need to apply a case insensitive collation to either operand to make the comparison case insensitive.

E.g.

```sql
WHERE username COLLATE XXX LIKE '...'
```

where `XXX` should be a utf8mb4 collation (such as the `utf8mb4_general_ci` you've mentioned.).

Or

```
WHERE username LIKE '...' COLLATE YYY
```

where `YYY` should be a collation that match the character set of you connection.

For equality comparison, you should [unquote the JSON value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path) with `JSON_UNQUOTE()` or the unquoting extraction operator `->>`

E.g.

```sql
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(payload, '$.username'))
```

Or simply

```sql
payload->>'$.username'
```

The JSON type and functions work way different from ordinary data types. It appears that you are new to it. So I would suggest you to read the manual carefully before putting it into a production environment.